# Does military spending include academic R&D budgets too?

Tags: military, education, public-funding

Does [military spending](https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/military-spending-by-country) include the R&D funds provided to the academic institutions too?

For example, suppose the government of a country hires a university faculty to do some research with the aim of developing a military weapon. The university, in turn, hires professors and PhD students to accomplish the task.

Is this fund considered a part of military spending or education spending?

Comment: You are long enough on this site that you should know that for things like this, no *binding* interational definitions exist. So why ask the question?

Comment: @user366312 this is a good question but  as currently written not a good Stack Exchange question post. Instead of asking for answer authors for their own views, it would be better to ask how governments actually do this. This allows for fact-based answers. However the problem is that you have not specified a country so it's unclear how exactly to answer.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on who does the considering and why. [SIPRI](https://www.sipri.org/databases/milex/frequently-asked-questions#1-definition) counts military R&D, but it acknowledges that the exact boundary can be difficult to draw. There is no generally accepted, legal definition for things like that.

Answer (score 2):

The usual academic system of a university is based on the peer-reviewed publications, so everything notable it discovers needs to go public. Nobody will work on topic they are not allowed to make the publications from, unless maybe a huge funding would allow to support irrelevant projects as well. Even in this case, it may be difficult to find PhD students and post-docs to work on secret projects as they are often on temporary positions. "What is your scientific background?" - "It is all secret, no publications" is not the most promising path of the interview.

Hence funding military research through the usual academic system brings no military advantage, as the discoveries will likely leak to the enemy. Military research must be done in a separate, properly secured and guarded research institution, by researchers with permanent positions and likely no right to leave.

Comment: How about Cranfield University in the UK?

Comment: As much as I get, they have partnership with Royal Military College of Science but I think it is about teaching, not research.

Comment: NATO offers academic grants through its [Science for Peace and Security](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/78209.htm) programme. These can be related to non-classified civil security. One aim is to train scientists who may in time move into "direct" military R&D.

Comment: @Stančikas, *but I think it is about teaching, not research.* --- absolutely incorrect!  Just go through their website.

Comment: In the US, a *ton* of defense research happens at universities or university-affiliated research centers. MIT Lincoln Lab, JHU APL, and multiple national labs are tied to or operated by universities. Los Alamos developed the nuclear bomb while it was being run by the University of California. Defense and intelligence agencies hand out research grants to universities all the time. Often it's unclassified. Other times it may be classified, in which case professors decide if it's worth doing.

Comment: @Stančikas, https://www.cranfield.ac.uk/research-projects/soil-health-evaluation

Comment: Cranfield University I see works on some very interesting projects but none of them looks   strictly military. Cybersecurity and surveilance have peaceful applications as well. The nuclear bomb Manhatan project was done by recruited high profile researchers in specialized institution that has been constructed for that.

Comment: @cpast how to they achieve not sharing they results with North Korea?

Comment: @Stančikas The same export controls that would apply to anything else. If it's unclassified and not subject to arms control rules, they don't worry about it. If it's unclassified and *is* subject to arms control rules (e.g. a lot of rocketry stuff), they apply those rules. If it's classified, they don't share it with uncleared people.

Comment: Despite your claim, academics can and do work on classified projects. Sometimes they do it on a short-term leave of absence or as a side project outside of their university. Sometimes they do it under university auspices (not all universities allow classified research at the university, but many do). When students do classified work, they just say "that project was classified so I can't show you the results" -- in math, for instance, an undergrad who does an NSA research internship would cite it as experience and share their letter of recommendation because they can't share the results.

Comment: I had long carrier in academia but I never actually worked on classified projects and never met anybody who did. Something that is subject to "export rules" cannot be printed in a normal scientific journal as the fundamental requirement is giving enough information to reproduce the experiment/algorithm in completeness.